# Free app with outlining as good as WordPerfect?

Tags: software-rec, word-processing, outline

I don't know how many of you have ever used WordPerfect's built in outlining, but let me tell you, it's fast and sweet. Tab to go down a level (e.g. I. to A. to 1.) shift+tab to go up. I guess I could stand slightly different keys. My word processor of choice is currently AbiWord, I think (Windows). If I could integrate with AbiWord or if a newer version has it (I have 2.6.4), that would be great.

Know of anything like that?

Edit 10/2: free would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen how good WordPerfect's outlining is, but to use outlining mode in [OpenOffice.org](http://openoffice.org), navigate to `Edit -> Navigator` from the menu. Works very well from my perspective. OOo is free and open source software.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'll have to grab a recent installer for OpenOffice. I've used it before (Win and Linux).

Comment: the only thing NOT overrated with OOo is the price, but that's just my opinion. i've tried it every now n then, but never grew fond of it.

Comment: Ah, forgot about this. If I don't get another better answer after a while, I'll check this.

Comment: Finally got a new OpenOffice installer. Looks like it's going to be more like I'm used to - handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **[Jarte](http://www.jarte.com/)** Plus. [Auto Outline](http://www.jarte.com/help_new/creating_outlines.html) actually was one of the reasons why I paid the €13 they're asking for the 'upgrade'. Brilliant little word processor, even the **[free version](http://www.jarte.com/download.html)**. Insanely fast at an incredibly low footprint (even with massive documents). Customizable 'Clickless Operation' is one of my favorite features.

[image]

*Jarte supports DOCX and is portable.*